# Get current username in Julia (Linux)

Tags: linux, julia

I must be doing something stupid, but I can't seem to retrieve the current username using Julia. The closest function in `Base` appears to be `gethostname()`, but that returns the computer name, not the username. I tried system calls but am having trouble due to the interpolation character `$`. Specifically, although `echo $USER` returns the appropriate username in a terminal, when I try the following in Julia I get various errors or incorrect answers:

```
run(`echo $USER`)
run(`echo "$USER"`)
run(`echo '$USER'`)
run(`echo '$'USER`)
run(`echo \$USER`)
```

I guess the issue is that `Julia` is misinterpreting the `$` as an interpolation, but I've got no idea how to get around this.

Any ideas?

Comment: FWIW `run(\`sh -c 'echo $USER'\`)` would have worked (but the accepted answer is far better!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An easy workaround:

```
run(`whoami`)
```

But unnecessary, as this works:

```
ENV["USER"]
```

Comment: Brilliant. The `ENV["USER"]` approach is definitely the way to go. For the sake of completeness, any chance you could comment on what is going wrong with my `echo $USER` approach? Either way, +1+Tick (as soon as SO lets me).

Comment: `run` does not run a shell; and the shell is what you need to interpolate the environment variables. `run` will interpolate *Julia* variables though, in a shell-like way. Read more [here](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/running-external-programs/).

Answer (score 3):

This works on both Linux and Windows:

```
splitdir(homedir())[end]
```

Answer (score 2):

A portion of the accepted answer no longer works.  Rather than ENV["USER"], the current method is:

```
ENV["USERNAME"]
```